# Getting the current logged user in Symfony ParamConverter annotation expression?

Tags: symfony

Symfony ParamConverter allow to pass an [expression](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html#2-fetch-via-an-expression) which uses the expression language feature:

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("order", class=Order::class, options={
 *     "expr": "repository.findByUser(user)"
 * })
 */
public function getOneAction()
{
}
```

However, this wil throw an error about the user variable not being available:

> Error parsing expression -- "repository.findByUser(user)" -- (Variable "user" is not valid around position 23 for expression `repository.findByUser(user)`.).

Does anyone knows how to access it?

Comment: What is your route ? Which "param" do you want to "convert" ?

Comment: Route isn't important: I just want to get the current logged user inside the expr. The expr option is a language expression string, but I can't find a way to get the current user variable inside it

Comment: Well I asked because there is no way to get the current user without creating a custom param converter and I was wondering if your url was something like `user/5/orders`

Comment: There is no built-in way to do what you're looking for to my knowledge. But since you already mentioned ParamConverter, the simplest way to do this, is to take `ParamConverter` annotation and `DoctrineParamConverter` service as an example and build your own. For actual symfony versions you may use the same approach with http-kernel's `ValueResolver` attribute